# Datatables squaredFour checkbox multidelete feature

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, checkbox, datatables

I am working on a project, which displays the data through datatables jquery plugin. In the first column of the datatable, I put a checkbox specifically, a bootstrap squaredFour checkbox. So, the first column in all the rows, has the checkbox. The next task is to be able to delete all the rows that are checked. I have a delete button at the top, which gets activated if there is atleast one checked row. Once the user clicks on delete button, he should be able to delete the row.

I do not understand, for some reason, I am not able to select more than one row. Once I check on one checkbox, it is selected and if I try to select other checkbox, the selected checkbox is getting unchecked. All this is happening only for first checkbox. Is this because of bootstrap?

This is the code for the checkbox. I returned it as a table data,

```
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
           // "ajax": "http://localhost:9080/dataTable/tests/user.php"
                "ajax" : {
                    "url" : "http://localhost:9080/swetha/swetha_gmail_to_bbe/trunk/public/" + "swethasemail/mail-ajax/get-data-table/format/json/",
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 0,
                        "orderable": false,
                        "className": "dt-body-center",
                        "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
                             return '<div class="squaredFour "><input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" /><label for="squaredFour"></label></div>';
                         },

                }],
```

In the above code it returns a checkbox that is populated in the td field in the datatable. [The checkboxes on the user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXFbT.png)

Please suggest me a solution for this. Or if there is any other possibility to implement a checkbox feature on datatable for multi delete, please let me know.

Comment: What happens if you shift (or control) -click a checkbox? Does it select multiple or does it still only select one?

Comment: @Chris. I tried ctrl click. When I do ctrl click first time, the first box in the column is seleted. When I do second time on some other checkbox, the firstbox is unchecked. There is no change to the clicked checkbox. When, I do check again, the first checkbox is checked. Everything happens only for the first checkbox.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Are you fully committed to the check boxes you have right now? If you're willing to try something else, there is a Datatables extension (written by the author of DataTables) called Select which makes it easy to select rows for manipulation (say, delete in your case). It also has a checkbox feature. Check it out [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/).

Comment: @Chris. Ok, I will try that. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can look at the Datatables extension:  https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/multi.html

Alternatively, here's how I got it work:

```
"columns": [
    {
        data: "approved", 
        render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" id="' + full.id + '"/>&nbsp;';
        }
    },
],
```

Note that every input has a unique ID.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. But, the main idea of the project is to build an email system like gmail. Once the user clicks on a row, it opens the body just like in gmail. The selection of a row should only be done through the checkbox. Once the user clicks on the checkbox, the row shoeld be selected. If he clicks on the row, it should open body. Is it possible to customize this select option to work only with checkbox?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  The select option allows you to select anywhere on the row.  If you only want the users selecting with checkboxes, see my solution above.

Comment: Do, I need to add that attribute columns in the

Comment: $('#example').DataTable( {
        select: {
            style: 'multi'
        },
        columns:  [
    {   data: "approved", 
        render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" id="' + full.id + '"/>&nbsp;';
        }
}], like this. Because, it did not seem to work like this?

Comment: Sorry, what? Do you need to add that attribute column where?  I think the only thing missing from your original solution was a unique ID on each checkbox.

Comment: Oh I see. So,  I just add the select feature and unique id and it is good?

Comment: It's up to you if you want to add the select feature.  You  will need to add a unique id to the checkbox for it to work.